# Why is haproxy ignoring the ssl keyword on a backend?

Tags: haproxy

I'm trying to setup backend servers with ssl between the LB and the Server
(172.16.12.34 is hosting http and https on the standard ports)

```
backend test
        balance source
        option httpchk
        default-server fastinter 7000 inter 500 fall 2
        server server1 172.16.12.34:443 check
        server server2 172.16.12.34:443 check ssl
        server server3 172.16.12.34:80 check
        server server4 172.16.12.34:80 check ssl
```

and I get the following unexpected output in stats

```
          Status     LastChk
server1   4m2s DOWN  * L7TOUT in 500ms
server2   4m2s DOWN  * L7TOUT in 501ms
server3   4m4s UP    L7OK/200 in 2ms
server4   4m4s UP    L7OK/200 in 2ms
```

It seems to be doing all the checks in http only and ignoring the ssl keyword.

Is this an Haproxy bug or have I got my config wrong? Or could this be compiler options? It is haproxy 1.6.4. Until I compiled with openssl it complained about the ssl keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded 1.6.5, compiling with openssl option and it works...

```
          Status     LastChk
server1   4m2s DOWN  * L7TOUT in 500ms
server2   4m4s UP    L7OK/200 in 1ms
server3   4m4s UP    L7OK/200 in 2ms
server4   4m2s DOWN  * L6RSP in 0ms
```

I can't see any bugs fixed that mention it so maybe the previous one didn't compile quite right.